# Use the special characters (asterisk) in the digitalBush masked input

Tags: c#, jquery, plugins, special-characters, mask

How could I add the special characters <kbd>*</kbd> *(asterisk)* in the [digitalBush masked input plugging](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)?

I read the documentation and looked around, and I could only achieve this editing the plugging itself, and this is something I don't wanna do that (avoid future problems with updates)

**Changing this:**

```
$.mask = {
    //Predefined character definitions
    definitions: {
        '9': "[0-9]",
        'a': "[A-Za-z]",
        '*': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: '_'
};
```

**Into this:**

```
$.mask = {
    //Predefined character definitions
    definitions: {
        '9': "[0-9]",
        'a': "[A-Za-z]",
        '~': "[A-Za-z0-9]"
    },
    dataName: "rawMaskFn",
    placeholder: '_'
};
```

The mask that I'm trying to achieve is this: `(99) 999*9?99999`

I made this code to fit my controller:

```
scriptMascara = string.Format("$('#{0}').mask('(99) 999*9?99999', {{placeholder:'{1}'}});", this.ClientID, PLACE_HOLDER);
```

*PS: The code above doesn't work, because the `*` is part of the definition of the plugging*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mask definition is just an associative array, so you should be able to remove the '*' reference without having to edit the plugin.

[Here is a fiddle with the mask working](http://jsfiddle.net/cb94N/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.mask.definitions['~'] = $.mask.definitions['*'];
    delete $.mask.definitions['*'];
    $('#mytext').mask('(99) 999*9?99999');
});
```